# Drag and drop data into shiny app

Tags: javascript, r, drag-and-drop, shiny

How can I drag and drop data into a shiny app?  I can drag and drop into an area and read it with javascript, but I'm not sure how to have shiny register it so I can process it on the server.  Here is an example setup -- it's kinda long b/c I don't think there is a javascript function builtin to deal with drag-n-drop.

It currently should look like the following when run and a dataset "dat.csv" is dragged in.  The goal is register the data that has been drag-n-dropped into a variable in `input` so it can be processed in R.
[image]

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/styles.css", type="text/css"),
      tags$script(src="getdata.js")),
    h3(id="data-title", "Drop Datasets"),
    div(class="col-xs-12", id="drop-area", ondragover="dragOver(event)", 
      ondrop="dropData(event)"),
    tableOutput('table'),  # doesn't do anything now

    ## debug
    div(class="col-xs-12",
      tags$hr(style="border:1px solid grey;width:150%"),
      tags$button(id="showData", "Show", class="btn btn-info", 
        onclick="printData('dat.csv')")),
    div(id="data-output")  # print the data
  )
)
```

#### server.R

```
## Make a sample dataset
# write.csv(data.frame(a=1:10, b=letters[1:10]), "dat.csv", row.names=FALSE)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable(input$data)  # this variable doesn't exist
}
```

#### www/getdata.js

```
var datasets = {};
var dragOver = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
var dropData = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleDrop(e.dataTransfer.files);
};
var handleDrop = function(files) {
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(file) {
        return function(e) {
        datasets[file.name.toLowerCase()] = e.target.result;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var src = "https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/office/512/e42-512.png";
        div.id = "datasets";
        div.innerHTML = [
            "<img class='thumb' src='", src, "' title='", encodeURI(file.name),
            "'/>", "<br>", file.name, "<br>"].join('');
        document.getElementById("drop-area").appendChild(div);
        };
    })(f);
    reader.readAsText(f);
    }
};
// debug
var printData = function(data) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = datasets[data];
    document.getElementById("data-output").appendChild(div);
};
```

#### www/css/styles.css

```
#data-title {
    text-align:center;
}

#drop-area {
    background-color:#BCED91;
    border:2px solid #46523C;
    border-radius:25px;
    height:90px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:12px;
}

#drop-area #datasets {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:small;
    margin-right:8px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.thumb {
    height:45px;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need to add the following line into the js file

```
datasets[file.name.toLowerCase()] = e.target.result;
# Add this line
Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", datasets);
```

Then you can use `input$mydata` in the server code. Note that it's a list, so you'll need to iterate through it (also necessary if you plan to drop several files).

Complete code (that also displays multiple csv files, note that if you drop multiple files with the same name, only one will be displayed):

getdata.js (add one line as above)

styles.css (no change)

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$link(rel="stylesheet", href="css/styles.css", type="text/css"),
              tags$script(src="getdata.js")),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h3(id="data-title", "Drop Datasets"),
        div(class="col-xs-12", id="drop-area", ondragover="dragOver(event)", 
            ondrop="dropData(event)")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        uiOutput('tables')
      )
    )

  )
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$mydata, {
    len = length(input$mydata)
    output$tables <- renderUI({
      table_list <- lapply(1:len, function(i) {
        tableName <- names(input$mydata)[[i]]
        tableOutput(tableName)
      })
      do.call(tagList, table_list)
    })
    for (name in names(input$mydata)) {
      output[[name]] <- renderTable(read.csv(text=input$mydata[[name]]))
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I just spent about an hour trying to get this to work, then I realised it's because I had `shiny.onInputChange( )`, with a lower case `s`  !

Comment: Is it possible to do it for other than text files? I have tried it with .xlsx but unfortunately it doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @AlexNevsky you'll need to modify the `www/getdata.js` file in the original question to read an xlsx file. There is a code snippet here https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx (near middle of the page, "HTML5 drag-and-drop using readAsBinaryString")

Answer (score 9):

As of August 2017 this functionality is now provided by `fileInput` directly from `shiny`! How wonderful.

Here's the blogpost announcing the feature https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/08/15/shiny-1-0-4/